# Programmatic configuration of TCP in JGroups

Tags: jgroups

How can I set fields like

```
thread_pool.enabled
thread_pool.queue_max_size
thread_pool.rejection_policy
```

for TCP protocol in Java-code? The general method setValue(...) does not accept these strings as valid property names while the provided tcp.xml does contain these. The JGroups API has no direct setters for these either.

Thanks!
Katalin

Answer (score 2):

Protocol.setValue("thread_pool_enabled", true);